# Print Consecutive numbers by comparing two parameters

Tags: java, for-loop

input `3,5` output should be `3,4,5`

input `5,3` output should be `5,4,3`

And the code

```
public static void test(int a, int b) {
        if(a>b) {
            for (int i = a; i >= b; i--) {
                System.out.print(i + "\t");
            }
        }else if(a<b) {
            for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
                System.out.print(i + "\t");
            }
        }
    }
```

It works but looks a little messy. Is it possible to do without `if else` thing? Only one loop.

Comment: Seems more appropriate for CodeReview than StackOverflow

Comment: @Deckard - You can remove the else part and add `return` inside the `if`

Comment: You're not outputting the right format; you specified comma's but you're outputting tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution which handle also boundary values correctly could be

```
public static void test(int start, int end) {
    int current = start;
    int stepWidth = current <= end ? +1 : -1;
    while (current != (end + stepWidth)) {
        System.out.print(current + "\t");
        current += stepWidth;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

**edit** Another one using a for loop.

```
public static void test(int start, int end) {
    int stepWidth = start <= end ? 1 : -1;
    for (int current = start; current != end + stepWidth; current += stepWidth) {
        System.out.print(current + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

**executions**

```
test(3, 5);
test(5, 3);
test(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 3, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
test(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE + 3);
```

**output**

```
3   4   5   
5   4   3   
2147483644  2147483645  2147483646  2147483647  
-2147483648 -2147483647 -2147483646 -2147483645
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this version?

```
public static void test(int a, int b) {
    int d = b > a ? 1 : -1; 
    for (int i = a; i != b; i+=d) {
        System.out.print(i + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: `test(3,5)` prints `3,4` missing 5

Comment: The simplest and clever, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This my solution, feedback appreciated.

```
public static void test(int a, int b) {
            int middle = (a < b) ? (b - 1) : (a - 1);
            System.out.println(a + "," + middle + ","+b);
        }
```

Above will work only when a != b.

Comment: I never intended only for `3,4,5` or `5,4,3`. `3,4,....n`, `n, n-1, ...3` doesn't work